# Angular 11 close bootstrap modal when submitting the form

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with angular 11. In my app I need to close the modal after clicking on submit button.
Tried to use  data-dismiss="modal" on submit button, but it ignoring the logic of my onSubmit method.

here is my modal

```
        <div class="container">
          <div>
              <form [formGroup]="FormData" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(FormData.value)">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="User name" formControlName="userName" required>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="FormData.controls.userName.invalid && (FormData.controls.userName.dirty || FormData.controls.userName.touched)"
                     class="alert alert-danger">
                  <div *ngIf="FormData.controls.userName.errors.maxlength">
                    Maximum length should be 256 characters
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="FormData.controls.userName.errors.required">
                    Name is required.
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email"
                         formControlName="email" required>
                  <div *ngIf="FormData.controls.email.invalid && (FormData.controls.email.dirty || FormData.controls.email.touched)"
                       class="alert alert-danger">
                    <div *ngIf="FormData.controls.email.errors.required">
                      E-mail is required.
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="FormData.controls.email.errors.email">
                      Email should be correct
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="message" name="message"></textarea>

                  <div *ngIf="FormData.controls.message.invalid && (FormData.controls.message.dirty || FormData.controls.message.touched)"
                       class="alert alert-danger">Maximum length should be 1000 characters
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modal seems to be missing a start:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" [style]="{'display':display}">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

I use bootstrap style but without bootstrap js. Hence the additional `[style]="{'display':display}"` piece. In Typescript I match this up with:

```
    onSubmit() {
        this.display='none'
```

Changing the style closes the model. Depending on your environment this may / may not work for you.